# GROUP BY Clause SOQL

Tags: soql, trigger

**How do I create a SOQL GROUP BY using custom field?**

For example:

```
SELECT id, name, Cultura__c 
FROM SC_VPM__c 
GROUP BY Cultura__c
```

This returns an error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY.
```

Comment: In that particular GROUP BY clause, SC_VPM_c and Cultura_c should be SC_VPM__c and Cultura__c (two underscores). Was that the problem?

Comment: In addition to the lack of underscore, you can only select the Culture__c field in addition to aggregate functions such as count, min, max, etc

Comment: What did you try? What errors did you receive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to group with a custom field just like a standard one. The main difference is the result from a group by query is that it becomes an AggregateResult sObject.

Salesforce Documentation of SOQL GROUP BY:
[http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm)

Comment: Some additional considerations when using Group By, please check out this official document from Salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm

Answer (score 3):

This is exclusively for `SOSL` AND `SOQL`.  Defined at this link:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause without an aggregated function to query all the distinct values, including null, for an object. The following query returns the distinct set of values stored in the LeadSource field.

```
SELECT LeadSource
FROM Lead
GROUP BY LeadSource
```

Answer (score 0):

### Salesforce group by example

The gotcha is that in SOQL, you can't use a bare `count()` in a group by query.

As a work around, you can specify a field to go inside the count like this:

```
select mycolumn, count(id)
from Opportunity
group by mycolumn
```

This produces results for me:

```
mycolumn              Unknown_Field__1
skipper               5
kowalski              3
rico                  1
```

**A more advanced query using group by:**

This gets the unique values of insurancecarrier__c and how many there are in the Object called Opportunity.  It sorts descending by the 2nd column, and limits to 100 results.

```
select insurancecarrier__c, count(id)
from Opportunity
group by insurancecarrier__c
order by count(id) desc
limit 100
```